# Trying to get rid of a single whitespace at the beginning of a text in a modal, the rest of the overflow is fine

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile, styled-components

[image]

Here is an example of an image. Notice the odd white space at the beginning, before the "t" in testing. The rest of the text overflow is all flush to the left side...

The text is styled using styled components, below is the code for it. It is nested within a view with flex: 1. Apart from that, there are no problems. I tried this on so many different types of texts, I don't know why overflow creates this offset.

```
export const Description = styled.Text `
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: Lato_400Regular;
    color: #444444;
`
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: May I ask a silly question that you sure your string does not have a padding space ( ) before 'testing'?

Comment: @PeterTam nope I double checked

Comment: Then you may need to share your full code about this section, otherwise this is not enough to recreate your issue.

Comment: @PeterTam you were right actually... I had a space between <Text> {thing} </Text>... I didn't realize

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.trim()` or `trimStart()` to be specific, this removes white space at the beginning.